# Зависимости из NuGet в CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, кроссплатформенность, nuget, зависимости

Есть win проект на c++, который нужно перенести на linux. Первым шагом было решено перейти с солюшенов студии на CMake. Мне выпало разбираться с внешними зависимостями. Оказалось что проект тянет их через NuGet.

Собственно вопрос, как прописать в CMake пути к пактам NuGet?

Была надежда, что можно в консольном режиме написать что-то вроде `nuget.exe get_path boost`, но подобного функционала в нем и близко не оказалось.

Answer (score 0):

В вопросе «[A NuGet-aware find_package for cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32020750/2553424)» участник Ben [предложил](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38908301/2553424) следующий, как он выразился, костыль:

```
find_program(NUGET nuget)
if(NOT NUGET)
  message(FATAL "Cannot find nuget command line tool.\nInstall it with e.g. choco install nuget.commandline")
else()
  execute_process(COMMAND ${NUGET} install foolib)
endif()
```

Comment: Так это он ставит пакет. А как теперь получить путь к include этого пакета? Или я что-то недопонял?